# SnakeYAML - Where is documentation and project homepage (is it still alive)?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm  trying to figure out how to fine control a specific feature in SnakeYaml (local tags).

Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to find a project homepage or the repository of Snake Yaml?

All references I find point to either a website, that seems to have been hacked (www dot snakeyaml dot org - not putting the link here as the site is clearly hacked) or to a bitbucket repository which is private.

Is that project still alive? If not, is there someone having the latest version of the original source code (I assume it is open source, but can't even find that out) who could publish that on a public github so that work can continue?

Comment: Upvoting despite this being off-topic for StackOverflow due to the sheer gravity of this issue: The repository has been moved, no redirect has been put in place, and it is non-trivial to find it again. Hopefully this question can point people in the right direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/snakeyaml-core/c/b_zrgaxL2dQ):

> Dear all,
> important news.
> The SnakeYAML team was using snakeyaml.org domain a few years.
> From this year on the domain was not continued any longer.
> Please refer to the new home:
> https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml
>
> And its mirror:
> https://github.com/snakeyaml/snakeyaml
>
> As you can see there is an important change, the project went away from the personal account.
>
> Cheers,
> Andrey

How they can do this without redirecting the original repository is beyond me.